# Complexity of multiplication reducing modulo N after each step

Tags: complexity-theory

I've been thinking about this question for a while. What is the complexity of multiplication if you reduce modulo N after each step?

I know the complexity of multiplication is O(m^2) (where m is the number of digets). Would reducing mod N after each step multiply it by a factor O(N^2)?
So the total complexity would be O(m^2)*O(N^2)?

Comment: Can you explain by what you mean by "after each step?" I think there are some interesting questions here, but I'm not sure specifically what you're getting at.

Comment: By after each step I mean, if I wanted to calculate 21*15, first I would multiply 5*21=(5*1)+(20*5). Then, I would reduce each part by mod(whatever) let's say 4 so we would have (1)+(0)=1. Second I would calculate 10*21=(10*20)+(10*1)=(0)+(2)=2. Then I would add them together to get 3, which mod 4 is still 3.